# Links from Discord is stuck

Tags: linux, browser, xdg, discord

My default browser set correctly:

```
XDG_UTILS_DEBUG_LEVEL=2 xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/https
Checking /home/user/.config/mimeapps.list
userapp-Nightly-T8BWRZ.desktop
```

`&BROWSER` is unset and `xdg-open https://www.google.com` works good. But when i click any link in discord: `/opt/firefox-nightly/firefox-bin https://www.google.com` process is spawned and not visible in my wm (bspwm) despite executing `/opt/firefox-nightly/firefox-bin https://www.google.com` manually works good. But according to htop process is working and drain cpu/memory. I tried different browsers, xdg-open replacments and settins/unsetting folloving envs:

```
DESKTOP_SESSION=
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=
```

No luck, i don't know how to debug this and almost sure that on same discord version in past everything worked fine. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

I found a bit hacky workaround: installed "linopen" package ([aur](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/linopen/)) with PROVIDE_XDG_OPEN=0 to not override existing "xdg-utils" package and symlinked linopen `/usr/bin/open` binary to `/usr/local/bin/xdg-open`, set $BROWSER and now links opens.